# Javascript Array Object vs Array Like Objects - Clarification

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, associative-array

I was trying to stringify an array-like object that was declared as an array object and found that JSON.stringify wasn't processing correctly array-like object when it is defined as an array object.

See below for more clarity, --> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/eCS7E/)

```
var simpleArray = []; //note that it is defined as Array Object 

alert(typeof simpleArray); // returns object -> Array Object

simpleArray ['test1'] = 'test 1';
simpleArray ['test2'] = 'test 2';

alert(JSON.stringify(simpleArray)); //returns []
```

It worked fine and returned me `{"test1":"test 1","test2":"test 2"}` when I changed

`var simpleArray = [];` to `var simpleArray = {};`.

Can someone shed some light or some reference where I can read more?

**Edit:**

Question: When typeof `simpleArray = []` and `simpleArray = {}` returned object, why JSON.stringify wasn't able to return `{"test1":"test 1","test2":"test 2"}` in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want an array.  When you want an "associative array" in JavaScript, you really want an object, `{}`.

You can distinguish them with `instanceof Array`:

```
[] instanceof Array // true
({}) instanceof Array // false
```

EDIT: it can process it.  It serializes all of the elements of the array.  However, to be an element, there must be a numeric key.  In this case, there are none.

This is nothing unique to JSON.  It's consistent with [`toSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toSource) and the `length` property.

Comment: I understand that part, what I wanted to know is why JSON.stringify couldn't process when declared as [].

Comment: Thank you!. I was looking for instanceof. I was trying to use typeof which was returning object in both the cases.

Comment: Since ES 5 there is also `Array.isArray(...)` (15.4.3.2) which by contrast is frame-safe. It can be emulated.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is the indexes. When you use an array `[]` the indexes can only be positive integers.

So the following is wrong:

```
var array = [ ];
array['test1'] = 'test 1';
array['test2'] = 'test 2';
```

because `test1` and `test2` are not integers. In order to fix it you need to use integer based indexes:

```
var array = [ ];
array[0] = 'test 1';
array[1] = 'test 2';
```

or if you declare a javascript object then the properties can be any strings:

```
var array = { };
array['test1'] = 'test 1';
array['test2'] = 'test 2';
```

which is equivalent to:

```
var array = { };
array.test1 = 'test 1';
array.test2 = 'test 2';
```

Comment: So what happens when you do `var simpleArray = []; simpleArray ['test2'] = 'test 2';`?

Comment: @MattFenwick, what happens is that contrary to what you might expect: `simpleArray.length = 0` which means that there are no elements in this array. You could still use `simpleArray.test2` to access the property you have defined. It's just confusing code that should be avoided.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation but, what I wanted to know is why JSON.stringify couldn't process when declared as []. I tried to use typeof and it returned me object in both cases. I am going to add this to my question.

Comment: @SKS, you have declared `simpleArray` as array - `[]`. This means that you need to use integer based indexes. In your example you haven't. So in this case `simpleArray.length = 0`, it's as if this array didn't contain any elements. So it's perfectly normal that the `JSON.stringify` method will serialize this empty array to `[]`. You just violated the rule that arrays must have integer based indexes and bad things happen when you violate rules.

Comment: I was able to figure out that much, but then was wondering when typeof was returning object and why JSON.stringify wasn't able to process. Now I clearly understand that it detects as an Array using if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(value) === '[object Array]') { and iterates thru length which is 0 and so the result is []. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 2):

> *"Can someone shed some light or some reference where I can read more?"*

When you're dealing with `JSON` data, you can refer to [json.org](http://json.org) to read about the requirements of the specification.

In `JSON`, an `Array` is an order list of values separated by `,`.

[image]

So the `JSON.stringify()` is simply ignoring anything that couldn't be represented as a simple ordered list.

So if you do...

```
var simpleArray = [];
simpleArray.foo = 'bar';
```

...you're still giving an Array, so it is expecting only numeric indices, and ignoring anything else.

Because `JSON` is language independent, the methods for working with `JSON` need to make a decision about which language structure is the best fit for each `JSON` structure.

So JSON has the following structures...

```
{} // object
[] // array
```

You should note that though the look very similar to `JavaScript` objects and arrays, they're not strictly the same.

Any `JavaScript` structures used to create `JSON` structures must conform to what the `JSON` structures will allow. This is why the non-numeric properties are <s>removed</s> excluded.

While `JavaScript` doesn't mind them, `JSON` won't tolerate them.

Comment: Non-numeric properties (better: properties with non-numeric *name*) are not removed. They are not considered for iteration in the first place.

Comment: @PointedEars: That was poor wording. I meant removed as a matter of perspective of the developer, as in *"Hey, they're in my Array object, but not in my JSON text!"*. I should have said *"excluded"*.

Answer (score 1):

When `JSON.stringify` encounters an array, it iterates in a similar way to a `for` loop from `0` to `simpleArray.length` to find the values. For example:

```
var a = [];
a[5] = "abc";
alert(JSON.stringify(a)); // alerts [null,null,null,null,null,"abc"]
```

Therefore setting properties on it will be completely invisible to JSON.

However defining the object with `{}` makes JSON treat it as an object, and therefore it loops over the object's properties (excluding inherited properties from the prototype chain). In this manner it can find your `test1` and `test2` properties, and successfully returns what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between `Array` instances and other objects are specified in the [ECMAScript Language Specification, Edition 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), section 15.4.

You will find there that while you can use the bracket property accessor syntax with *all* object references --

```
objRef[propertyName]
```

-- `Array` instances are special. Only using a parameter value which string representation is that of an unsigned 32-bit integer value less than 2<sup>32</sup>-1 accesses an element of the encapsulated array structure, and write access affects the value of the `Array` instance's `length` property.

Section 15.12 specifies the `JSON`   object and its `stringify` method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, everything is an object, so even Arrays.
This is why you get:

```
>> var l = [1, 2];
>> typeof l
"object"
```

Arrays are stored the same way as objects. So, in fact, arrays are only hashtable objects. The index you provide when accessing e.g.

```
>> l[0]
```

is not interpreted as an offset, but is hashed and then searched for.

So Arrays, are just objects (with some builtin array-methods) and so you can treat them like objects and put a value under a certain key.
But only those keys indexed by numbers are used to compute the length.

```
>> var l = []
>> l.length
0
>> l[5] = 1;
>> l.length
6
>> l
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 1]
>> l.hello = "Hello"
>> l.length
6
```

Read [Array - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Description) for more information
and [Associative Arrays considered harmful](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) why you should not do this.

Comment: Not *everything* is an object. There are primitive values. But there is no "Javascript", there are several different ECMAScript implementations.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not semantically correct, but because most JavaScript engines are really nice on the programmer they allow these types of *mistakes*.

A quick test case:

```
var a = [];
a.b = "c";
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));//yields [], and not {"b":"c"} as you might expect
```

This might be because of some strictness in `JSON.stringify` which still treats `a` like an `Array`.
I wouldn't worry about it overly much. This is a situation that should not occur in your program because it is an error. [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) is a popular tool to catch these and many more potential problems in your code.

Comment: I thought it was rather obvious: you can't declare string keys in `Array`s. Just because most JavaScript engines accept it doesn't make it _correct_. I hope you thought the down-vote was worth it.

Comment: You have serious misconceptions as to the nature of JavaScript, of ECMAScript objects, and what belongs to the syntax of a programming language. One comment is to short for that. *There are no keys.* Objects have *properties* with names. Property names are *strings*, accessed with `[`…`]`, `.`, or implicitly (scope chain). JavaScript is an ECMAScript implementation. Of *JavaScript* there are only two production-quality "implementations": SpiderMonkey and Rhino; others like JScript are *ECMAScript* implementations. To be continued …

Comment: `Array` instances are objects. Some property names refer to elements with them, *per Specification*. Using a "string key" with property access on `Array` instances may be a *semantic* error if you want to access an element of the array structure. Think about this: `var a = []; a["0"] = "b"; console.log(a["length"], a.length, a, a[0]); /* _syntax_ error _in the following_, because 0 is not an identifier: */ a.0;`

Comment: You have a strange way of trying to be constructive. You could have simply suggested I change it to "semantically". I suppose what you mean is that `a.b = "c"` is valid given that a is an `ArrayObject`. So it is syntactically allowed, because you can assign properties to `Objects`, but it's semantically wrong because the value "c" will not appear in the `Array` when you `JSON.stringify` it. - I don't think arguing about jargon is the right scope.

Comment: This is not only about syntactic vs. semantic. It is about you not understanding the programming languages in question. I could have said "you have no clue what you are talking about", but thought explaining where you went wrong was more constructive.